# Using VSCode to debug or test apex

Tags: apex, debugging, vs-code

I retrieved source files from org using SFDX commands in VS code and then I updated some code and saved the file.

However, when  I try to run the anonymous debugger using `SFDX: Execute Anonymous Apex with Editor Contents`, I can see that the executed code is not the updated code.

How can I debug or test the local changes in VS code without pushing the change to org?

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy the file (right-click > SFDX: Deploy Source to Org) before running the script. Alternatively, you can use an auto-deploy setting/extension, such as [Mohith Shrivastava's extension](https://github.com/msrivastav13/mo-dx-plugin). The readme describes how to install this (requires two steps).

Comment: Isn't there a way to debug without pushing the changes to org?

Comment: @SachiDangalla No, execute anonymous runs on the server.